# Check IP country and display full country name

Tags: ip, country, country-codes

I use the following code to check the location of the users IP.
But this displays the country like 'US' and 'UK'.

How can I solve this to display the full country name?
Like 'United States' and 'United Kingdom'?

```
CODE:

<?php

$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

function ip_details($ip) {
  $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json");
  $details = json_decode($json, true);
  return $details;
}

$details = ip_details($ipaddress);
echo $details['country'];

?>
```

Comment: What is your problem? Does you code have error?

Comment: @weigreen No, it works fine! I only want to edit the displayed countrycodes into country names. Country is now displayed as "US" and I want to display it like "United States"

Comment: Hi Henk, you could use https://ipdata.co instead, we provide the fully country name, currency, currency symbol and calling code in addition to all the other datapoints directly from the API, with no extra work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look like you are using ipinfo's API.

They only provide you short country name.

However, [ipinfo's document](http://ipinfo.io/developers/full-country-name) said you can use "country.io"'s data to achieve your need.

Just convert it into php array, and you can transfer US to United States

```
<?php

$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$code = ["US" => "United States", "GB" => "United Kingdom"];

function ip_details($ip) {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json");
    $details = json_decode($json, true);
    return $details;
}

$details = ip_details($ipaddress);
if(array_key_exists($details['country'], $code)){
    $details['country'] = $code[$details['country']];
}
echo $details['country'];

?>
```

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is that in that case the countries are converted into English country names. I want to translate this into our own language. Is there a way to say, if value is "US" dispaly "Amerika"?

Comment: Just update my answer, you can change data in `$code` ,which `key` as country code, and `value` as your language's country name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use checkgeoip.com. It's free:

```
<?php
// set IP address and API key 
$ip = '72.229.28.185';
$api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

// Initialize CURL:
$ch = curl_init('https://api.checkgeoip.com/'.$ip.'?api_key='.$api_key);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Store the data:
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Decode JSON response:
$api_result = json_decode($json, true);

// Output the "city" object
echo $api_result['city'];
?>
```